# Automation Object Wizard causes IDE "Not Responding"

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I am new to Delphi programming and wanted to try making a simple automation server. I use Delphi XE2.

The instructions were quite simple, mainly 'follow the wizard'. I open the Automation Object Wizard through:

File --> New --> Other --> ActiveX --> Automation Object.

I fill in the fields, nothing strange. However, once I click 'OK', The IDE freezes over and claims to be "Not Responding". This happens both when I try the process in Windows 8.1 and Windows 7, on different computers. Nothing further happens and I need to close the IDE. I am, however, able to create an ActiveX library and add my interface et.c. in the design tab. But then I write my server implementation from scratch, which works but seems a bit unnecessary.

I am curious, has anyone else experienced this problem? Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong?

I am grateful for any help I can get!

Comment: Sounds like an ide bug. I think you just need to move on. It won't be fixed in xe2.

Comment: Too bad! I'll try other ways then.